# PYQT4 Python 3.4 Creating a form with lable

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt4

> I am trying to create a window with a label and i get this error
>   File "ui.py", line 16, in     mainWindow = MyForm()  File
>   "ui.py", line 9, in **init**    lbl = QtGui.QLable('Welcome Brats!',
>   self) ttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QLable'

```
             import sys 
        from PyQt4 import QtGui

        class MyForm(QtGui.QWidget):

            def __init__(self):
                super(MyForm, self).__init__()

                lbl = QtGui.QLable('Welcome Brats!', self)

                self.setGeometry(300,300,250,150)
                self.setWindowTitle(('Port Scaner'))
                self.show()

        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        mainWindow = MyForm()
        status = app.exec_()
        sys.exit(status)
```

Pyqt4 python3.4

Comment: Possibly a spelling error? Have you tried `QtGui.QLabel`?

Comment: Thank you. That was really silly of me.